# Цвет текста в phpdesigner8

Tags: php

Недавно начал работать с этой программой.
Цвет комментариев в коде хочу поменять с серого на другой.
Кто знает где задаются эти настройки?
Настройки поискал, видосы на ютуб посмотрел как настраивают, но именно эти параметры никто не меняет...

Answer (score 1):

[скриншот](http://s020.radikal.ru/i722/1407/47/0bdbbbb857b3.png)

Выбираете Инструменты -> Установки, дальше как показано на скрине. Во втором пункте выбираете язык, далее тыкаете мышкой по тому элементу, цвет которого нужно изменить.

Сам очень долго пользовался этой программой. Недавно перешел на PhpStorm. phpDesigner нервно курит в сторонке

Comment: Не хочу создавать новый вопрос. Может кто подскажет, как отключить подсказки. Надоедает что постоянно вылезает окно с переменными..

Comment: @rnddev, так это же хорошо что вылазит. Во первых, не ошибетесь в названии переменной, во вторых - это очень ускоряет написание кода

Comment: @mountpoint это то да, но то что это окно закрывает мне нужную область кода, просто ужасно напрягает

Comment: @rnddev, снимаете галочки где выделено красным - http://prntscr.com/42c8u2